# VB.NET: Optimize initialisation of multiple classes

Tags: vb.net, optimization, reflection

In a project of mine I'm currently doing this:

```
    addTemplateToList(New docNULL)
    addTemplateToList(New docAgenda)
    addTemplateToList(New docAgendaNew)
    addTemplateToList(New docOffer)
    :
      20 more
    :
    addTemplateToList(New docRequest)
```

all classes inherit docMain and addTemplateToList( X ) adds x to a List(Of docMain).

Now my question is: Is there a better way to do what's done in the code sample?

I thought of something like:

```
for all x as docMain in ALLAVAILABLECLASSES
  if x.className().beginswith("doc") then addTemplateToList(x)
next
```

Is this somehow possible in VB.net (Reflection?)?

Comment: Wouldn't you check whether the classes inherit docMain, rather than checking the prefix of the class name? Also it's arguably a "code smell" if you only ever have one instance of each class. For instance, is it possible that docAgenda could act like docAgendaNew if some private variables were set appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a quite simple solution to my problem:

```
    Dim m As Type = Type.GetType("mainARGQ.docCreator")
    For Each TypeObj As Type In [Assembly].GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        If TypeObj.BaseType Is m And TypeObj IsNot m Then
            addTemplateToList(Activator.CreateInstance(TypeObj))
        End If
    Next
```

Edit: Just wondering if there's a way to simplify "TypeObj.BaseType Is m And TypeObj IsNot m"

Comment: A class base type is never itself, so you can get rid of the And part.

Answer (score 0):

Google vb.net reflection gives:

http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/Reflection09122007031247AM/Reflection.aspx

Do note that although it will make your code more flexible/ shorter. This is not optimization, reflection is a generally expensive feature in programs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use reflection, even better use MEF ( http://www.codeplex.com/MEF ) so you can stick new modules on runtime or just by dropping a DLL.

As someone said before it won't make it faster yet less code more flexibility.